# is there any chance that Microsoft Release .Net framework versions for MacOS & Linux as in windows outside UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cross-platform

I'm currently involved in project for making a 3D CAM software specific to the hardware that our company makes, but here comes the problem.
the decision was to use qt & C++ to do the job as the software is required to be cross-platform. i.e. works on linux MacOS & Windows. but of corse this lead us to suffer in many painful ways, And as much as Qt is powerful it lacks a decent designer or in other words it's designer is no match for The Visual studio Designer or Microsoft Blend. plus also I've used WPF for the GUI Design & it was incredible. while when it comes to QtQuick the WPF Alternative in Qt, it's syntax is very simple and much easier than XAML but it's designer is the worst thing on earth. can you imagine that I prefer writing QML than using the designer? its very miserable.
plus when it comes to developing Apps using such a language as C++, it's like hell compared to using Such a language as C#.
of corse C++ is the most powerful language on earth and it's the industry standard and it's used to develop softwares for controlling nuclear rockets bla bla bla..., But even of this is true, who Needs such Power to just develop an application that just Opens 3D Files & Converts them into G-Code to be Executed on another machine?

I've been using C# for about 8 or 9 years now & believe me, it can almost do anything with almost the same performance of C++ apps, but with much less effort & in a more straightforward way in much less time.

so here's my question.
- why wouldn't Microsoft Implement their .Net framework on Linux & Mac to save us from this Suffering?
- also, When would developers be able to Write C# or VB On Any machine & compile the same Code AnyWhere?
isn't this why .Net was designed in the first place?

Also I think it's time to end-up the Qt legacy, they've been dominating the Cross-Platform Development With their false claims that they are the best, but actually they are just being used because they are the best of the worse.

I couldn't post such Suggestion to Microsoft, But I'm sure they do See our Posts on such Platforms as stack overflow, so I'd ask everyone who agrees with me to Put his comment below to Deliver our voice to Microsoft.

Comment: Have you looked into .NET Core?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s about the possible future of .NET.

Comment: Net in many cases is just a wrapper to call a windows dll.  The windows dll is not the same on all windows machines.  So when Microsoft comes out with new version of windows the Net Library doesn't have to change as long as the dll interface remains the same.  To implement on Mac or Linux you would need to create interfaces that behave like the windows dlls.

Comment: You mixed false facts with many of your personal opinions, and it is not a valid question to be answered. .NET Framework was designed to be Windows only, and without cross platform support at all, so Microsoft won't be able to ship it for other platforms. .NET Core is still relatively new in this area, and your current requirements (GUI apps on non-Windows platforms) are not yet part of its plan. https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: I think the closest thing you'll find to what you're looking for is Xamarin Forms.  You may find it's just as unwieldy as the other options, but it's the official MS solution at the moment and it has a similar designer experience as WPF and UWP. Unfortunately, while Xamarin Forms supports Windows and Mac, it doesn't provide built-in support for Linux.  There is an [open source project] aimed at adding Linux support, but I don't know enough about it to say how stable/feature-complete it currently is.  In any case, I'd keep an eye on Xamarin as the likely future candidate.

Comment: Oops.  I forgot to include the link to the [open source project](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/forms-gtk-progress).

Comment: You could also consider building a GUI using web standards, like in Electron.  That would be easy do develop and highly portable.